# Excel regular expression macro

Tags: regex, vba, excel

Looking at [Excel regular expression macro that will search one column for matches, paste the entire row of all matches in another worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18796382/excel-regular-expression-macro-that-will-search-one-column-for-matches-paste-th?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Is it possible to do the same but for cells that contain words. i.e starts with Mail or emails that contain .edu.

I was unable to comment on existing post as i am a new user

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array formula to do that.
In the example I assume you're looking for ".edu", values in A1:A5 and you want the results in D1 and down

write this formula in D1:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$5;SMALL(IFERROR(SEARCH("*.edu*";$A$1:$A$5)*(ROW($A$1:$A$5));"");ROWS($D$1:D1)))
```

Dont forget to Ctrl Shift Enter (to enter the formula - it is an array formula)

With this you get the first value in A1:A5 that contains ".edu", to get the others copy the formula down.

Now in D2 you get the second, in D3 the third....and so on...